# sending an email using codeigniter does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller ->

```
class Email extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
}

public function index(){

    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
    );

    $config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'entertaxibvba@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'mypass',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);

    $this->email->from('entertaxibvba@gmail.com', 'EnterTaxi');
    $this->email->to('entertaxibvba@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Details nieuwe rit');
    $this->email->message('test test test');
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->send();
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

I have changed my php.ini , turned off my antivirus , ...
but nothing seems to work.

I get an error saying:

> fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>
> error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate
>
> verify failed

also I'm only learning coding for a few months now, so i'm sorry if it's an obvious mistake :)

Thanks

Comment: What is this `$mail->SMTPOptions`?

Comment: I dont actually know , I was searching for an answer and I found this

If I take it away I get another error => Message: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Comment: Don't disable SSL checks. You likely have an outdated PHP/curl.

Comment: How can I check if it is outdated ?

Comment: Are you trying to send e-mails from a localhost? may I suggest an alternative to gmail?

Comment: Is using for example hotmail on localhost a better alternative ?